# How to duplicate a row in excel several times

Tags: excel, datatables, duplicates

I have the following problem. I have two different data sources like the one belows:

Table 1:

| Client | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| Client 1 | 300 |
| Client x | 400 |

Table 2:

| Product |
| --- |
| Product 1 |
| Product x |

Huge thanks!

Im copy pasting manually X times but it take sa lot of time....

I want to automatically duplicate the Client row in the first table X times the different products resulting in something like that:

| Client | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Client 1 | Product 1 |
| Client 1 | Product 2 |
| Client 1 | Product 3 |
| Client 1 | Product 4 |
| Client x | Product 1 |
| Client x | Product 1 |

Comment: The search term you are looking for is `CrossJoin`. If you have Excel 365, see March 2022 article on [New Text and Array Functions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-new-text-and-array-functions/bc-p/3267036) for a solution. If not, you can do this in VBA and/or Power Query.

Comment: What is the logic to generate the repetition? Product 2,3,4 are not present in the second table. What is the logic to have more repetition for Client 1 than for Client x? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you could use vba to write a macro for that exact case.
You could popup a MsgBox with 1 input field and then copy the line with that function.

If you need some code pleas ask.

Sorry for the wait.

Here is the code you need as a Macro for copy paste the 1 line to how many lines you need.

`Sub Copy()
    'Here you get the input of how often to you want the first line to occure at the end.
    copyCount = Application.InputBox(prompt:="How often to you want have line 1 in document?", Type:=1)
    'Here the actual copy paste job will be done.
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("1:" & copyCount).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub`

Comment: This cannot be an answer to the question, but a comment.